# Abrir ventana url en ventana nueva jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

tengo esta función que llamo desde un select.

```
function CambiarEstadoPedido(que,id,cod,estado) { //tareas del seleccionador
if(que=="cambiar_estado") { InsertarModal('Pedidos','Pedi_CEstado','ConsPedido',id,estado,'450','410'); }
if(que =="Albaran") { window.open('http://google.es','Continue_to_Application','width=200,height=400');
return false; }
if(que =="Eliminar") { alert('guay es eliminar'); }

}
```

La idea es abrir una ventana nueva del navegador con una url pero pero por alguna razón que no alcanzo a comprender no funciona el window.open ¿en que me puedo estar equivocando?

si pongo un alert dentro de "que = "Albaran"" si fuciona, con lo que entiendo que hasta ahi llega bien el código.

Muchas gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda :)

Answer (score 3):

La única opción para que no se abra la ventana es, o bien `que != "Albaran"` o igual el navegador no te está abriendo la ventana secundaria porque te está preguntando (suelen poner un mensaje arriba para permitirlo). Aquí una imagen de lo que digo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y te dejo [aquí un jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c48j8zq1/) para que compruebes que funciona.

PD: No sé porque has puesto jQuery en el título....

Nos cuentas.

Comment: Anda, pues es verdad... pero eso va por defecto activado :( y no habra otra forma de abrir una ventana evitando ese bloqueador?

Comment: La verdad es que dudo mucho que se pueda evitar, es una característica del navegador y necesita la interacción del usuario. Investiga y si encuentras algo, compártelo ;)

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te dejo dos formas a ver si te sirven de ayuda.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 var ruta = "http://www.google.es";

 // Opcion 1
 $("#enlace1").click(function(){

  
  $("#enlace1").attr("href",ruta);
 
 });

 // Opcion 2
 $("#enlace2").click(function(){

  window.open(ruta, 'Nombre Ventana');
    return false;
   
 });

});
```

```css
#enlace2{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="enlace1" target="_blank" href="">Enlace 1 a Google<a/>
<br/><br/>
<a id="enlace2">Enlace 2 a Google<a/>
```

Comment: A mi no me funciona ninguno de los dos enlaces. ¿Se supone que así te saltas la validación del navegador de abrir ventana secundaria? No le encuentro mucho sentido, pero vaya, siempre se puede aprender algo nuevo...

Comment: Aquí no te van a funcionar porque estamos intentando abrir otras webs pruébalo en un fichero en tu ordenador, saludos

Comment: En safari tampoco se abren. el bloqueador actua y las bloquea

Comment: Esta probado en Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Opera, Safari (5.1.7) y funciona en todos, no puedo comprobar la ultima versión de Safari ya que no tengo mac, entonces no se si en alguna versión lo habrán bloqueado, revisa también si tienes algún plugin en el navegador que los bloquee tipo adblock